# Ruby fork multiple processes and track status of running/complete?

Tags: ruby, fork

I'm trying to fork children processes off and keep track of if the process is still running or has completed, but I don't want to block and wait for the process to complete as I need to be able to continue monitoring for new incoming requests and fork off additional child processes as needed.

Here is some basic sample code of what I'm trying to do.

```
loop do
  pid = fork do
    puts 'foo'
    exit 99
  end

  ret_pid = wait2(pid,  Process::WNOHANG) # Tried this, but it never gets a value
  if ret_pid
    puts 'got a returned pid'
  end
end
```

I've tried waiting using the `Process::WNOHANG` flag; this doesn't block, but it also never seems to get any type of return status.  I've tried both `wait` and `wait2`, but no difference.

I have also tried waiting just using `wait(pid)` which gets the status back from the child process, but this blocks so I end up with only a single forked process which doesn't do me any good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is more important to you, is it "checking for child process status" or being able to "fork off additional child processes as needed". If the latter than this might help you:

```
  queue = ['A','B','C','D']
  forks = []
  while queue.size > 0
    q = queue.shift
    forks << Process.fork do
      puts q
    end

    if forks.size >= 10
      forks.delete Process.wait 
    end
  end
```

You can keep pushing new elements to queue or if your goal is to loop forever then you can easily change it loop from `while` to `loop`.

With the `forks.size` you can set amount of the child processes being processes at the same time

Important thing to know about `Process.wait` is that when you don't pass parameters to it, it waits for any child process to finish and returns pid of that process.